# Simplest way to expose a JSON service in ASP.NET / DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, dotnetnuke

I need to create a backing service for a [jQuery token input field control](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).

Our application consists of controls for a (third-party) DotNetNuke module called SimpleWrapper. The way this module works is that it provides a lightweight but not very flexible way of displaying regular ASP.NET user controls on a DNN page. The caveat is these are `.ascx` controls, not `.aspx` pages.

I'm mostly at a loss at which of the various technologies available to use. I looked at ASMX services but those mostly seem tailored to producing generated JavaScript proxy code. I need to be able to:

- mount the service at a static URL
- have it accept a single string parameter
- have it produce JSON in a specific, but very simple format

I don't really need strong integration with ASP.NET, like being able to respond to a postback or some such. I'd also prefer something deployable just by adding a file, without having to edit configuration files. What would be a straightforward way to spit out a chunk of JSON in such an environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF (I think starting with version 3.51) has a nice "zero config" feature that integrates easily with IIS. All you have to do is

- create a JSON aware interface & service
- create a simple .SVC file in the IIS site.

You don't need to mess with funky `.config` files :-)

Example .SVC file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost
 Service="MyNamespace.MyService"
 Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Example interface & service implementation, something like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
        public string Test(string text)
        {
            return text; // whatever
        }

}

[ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.myservice.com")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContractAttribute]
    [WebInvokeAttribute(UriTemplate="Test", // change this accordingly
     ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, // change this accordingly
     RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, // change this accordingly
     BodyStyle=Wrapped)]
    string Test(string text);
}
```

Here is an extra cool link about all this: [WCF Web Services The Easy Way](http://www.codethinked.com/wcf-web-services-the-easy-way).

Comment: This looks like it should cover the requirements, thanks. One more thing, is it possible to access query string parameters in the service implementation?

Comment: @Inerdial: Yes, it's possible if you call the web service method in a GET request but you could also issue a POST request and modify your web service method to receive these parameters. See here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Comment: @Icarus I think I'm stuck with GET, the token input control only uses that and I don't feel like modifying it. It seems like the `UriTemplate` parameter is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[JSON Exposed thru Restful Service](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/2757/Simple-RESTful-JSON-web-services-with-DotNetNuke.aspx) 
This Link will guide you step by step on how to do what I believe to be what you are looking for has actual code sample

Comment: Hm, I'd prefer something that doesn't require editing configuration files to deploy, but it's not a showstopper.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why WCF Web services or `ASMX` Web Services are not suitable for what you say you need. Personally, that's the way I'd go (choosing WCF over ASMX).

I looked at the link DJ KRAZE posted and it uses an HTTP Handler plus uses some third party Javascript serializer (one extra dependency that isn't really needed since you have  JavascriptSerializer if needed).

Comment: ICaurus I am not truly sure what he's using or not using since he mentioned that it's not the normal .aspx pages there for I did not recommend a traditional .net approach ie WCF

Comment: They might very well be suitable. I'm fairly new to dotnetland, and am only vaguely aware of what technologies are available and what they can be made to do.